# Div following wrapper div floats behind wrapper

Tags: css, z-index, fluid-layout

I am working on a fluid grid (DreamWeaver CC) site. I have a header-Wrapper div containing stacked elements using z-index. I am now trying to add a div after the header-Wrapper but this div is floating behind the header-Wrapper. This is my first time working with z-index so I'm rather flummoxed.

I have tried position and display css elements for the mobileNav div and also tried to use a height element for the header-wrapper. Nothing. the mobileNav div seems to be ignoring the header-Wrapper altogether and acting like it is the first div in the gridContainer.

Thanks for your help

site: miki.nantucket.net/redac-2.php

---

### html

```
<body>
    <div class="gridContainer clearfix">
        <div id="header-wrapper" class="fluid">
        <div id="rotation" class="fluid "><?php include  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/includes/layout/rotations.php" ?></div>
        <div id="Weather" class="fluid "><?php include  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/includes/layout/weather.php" ?></div>
        <div id="Navigation" class="fluid "><ul>
        <li>Nav1</li>
        <li>Nav2</li>
        <li>Nav3</li>
        <li>Nav4</li>
        <li>Nav5</li>
        <li>Nav6</li>
        <li>This is not styled yet</li>
        </ul></div>
      </div><!--end header-wrapper-->
      <div id="mobileNav" class="fluid">This is the content for Layout Div Tag "mobileNav"</div>
     </div>
 </body>
```

---

### CSS

```
.fluid {
    clear: both;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    display: block;
}

.fluidList {
    list-style:none;
    list-style-image:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;        
}

/* Mobile Layout: 480px and below. */

.gridContainer {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 92.625%;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    clear: none;
    float: none;
    background-color:#FBFAF6;
}
#header-wrapper {
    position:relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
#rotation {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;

}
#Navigation {
    display:none;   
    width: 100%;
}   
#Weather {
    text-align:right;
    font-size:13px;
    padding:5px 0px 10px 0px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:50;
    top:0px;
    left:0;
    background: #4b829f;
    background: rgba(75,134,159, .8);
    color: #ffffff;
}
#mobileNav {
    position:relative;
}
.zeroMargin_mobile {
margin-left: 0;
}
.hide_mobile {
display: none;
}

/* Tablet Layout: 481px to 768px. Inherits styles from: Mobile Layout. */

@media only screen and (min-width: 481px) {

.gridContainer {
    width: 93.4166%;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    clear: none;
    float: none;
    margin-left: auto;
}
#header-wrapper {
}
#rotation {
}
#Navigation {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:100;
    top:49px;
    left:0;
    background: #4b8a9f;
  background: rgba(75,134,159, .8);
    color: #ffffff;
    width: 23.7288%;
}
#Weather {
}
#mobileNav {
}
.hide_tablet {
display: none;
}
.zeroMargin_tablet {
margin-left: 0;
}
}

/* Desktop Layout: 769px to a max of 1232px.  Inherits styles from: Mobile Layout and Tablet Layout. */

@media only screen and (min-width: 769px) {

.gridContainer {
    width: 88.875%;
    max-width: 1232px;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    clear: none;
    float: none;
    margin-left: auto;
}
#header-wrapper {
}
#rotation {
}
#Navigation {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:100;
    top:49px;
    left:0;
    background: #4b8a9f;
    background: rgba(75,134,159, .8);
    color: #ffffff;
    width: 17.7215%;
}
#Weather {
}
#mobileNav {
}
.zeroMargin_desktop {
margin-left: 0;
}
.hide_desktop {
display: none;
}
```

### }

### CSS for included responsive slider

```
/*responsive hero slider*/
.rslides {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  }

.rslides li {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  }

.rslides li:first-child {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  }

.rslides img {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  }
  .caption {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  margin:0;
  text-align: center;
  background: #4b8a9f;
  background: rgba(75,134,159, .8);
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size:18px;
  font-stretch:expanded;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you. Due to the various elements, I do need the absolute positioning but your comment about allowing for the space in the header-wrapper gave me an idea. I put an image into the header-wrapper, fiddled around with the z-index property here and there. Probably not the most elegant way to do it but it's working!

Thank you.

---

### html

```
<div class="gridContainer clearfix">
        <div id="header-wrapper" class="fluid">
               <div id="rotation" class="fluid "><?php include  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/includes/layout/rotations.php" ?></div>
        <div id="Weather" class="fluid "><?php include  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/includes/layout/weather.php" ?></div>
        <div id="Navigation" class="fluid "><ul class="navBump">
        <li>Nav1</li>
        <li>Nav2</li>
        <li>Nav3</li>
        <li>Nav4</li>
        <li>Nav5</li>
        <li>Nav6</li>
        <li>This is not styled yet</li>
        </ul></div>
 <div id="LogoWrapper" class="fluid "><div id="Logo" class="fluid "><img src="images/sitewide/Logo.png"></div><div id="LogoTag" class="fluid "><?php include  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/includes/layout/logtag.php" ?></div></div>        
     <img src="images/rotations/redac2/image1a.jpg">
      </div><!--end header-wrapper-->
      <div id="mobileNav" class="fluid">This is the content for Layout Div Tag "mobileNav"</div>
     </div>
```

---

### CSS

```
.fluid {
    clear: both;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    display: block;
}

.fluidList {
    list-style:none;
    list-style-image:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;        
}

/* Mobile Layout: 480px and below. */

.gridContainer {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 92.625%;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    clear: none;
    float: none;
    background-color:#FBFAF6;
}
#header-wrapper {
    position:relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
#header-wrapper img {
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
}
#rotation {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:5;  
    margin-left: 0; 
    width: 100%;
}
#Navigation {
    display:none;   
    width: 31.0344%;
    margin-left: 0;
}

#Weather {
    text-align:right;
    font-size:13px;
    padding:5px 0px 10px 0px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:50;
    top:0px;
    left:0;
    background: #4b829f;
    background: rgba(75,134,159, .8);
    color: #ffffff;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
#mobileNav {
    z-index:0;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 0;
}
#LogoWrapper {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:1000;
}
#Logo {
}
#LogoTag {
    font-size:12px;
    color:#797979;
}
.zeroMargin_mobile {
margin-left: 0;
}
.hide_mobile {
display: none;
}

/* Tablet Layout: 481px to 768px. Inherits styles from: Mobile Layout. */

@media only screen and (min-width: 481px) {

.gridContainer {
    width: 93.4166%;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    clear: none;
    float: none;
    margin-left: auto;
}
#header-wrapper {
}
#rotation {
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 0;
}
#Navigation {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:100;
    top:49px;
    left:0;
    background: #4b8a9f;
    background: rgba(75,134,159, .8);
    color: #ffffff;
    width: 23.7288%;
    margin-left: 0;
}
#Weather {
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 0;
}
#mobileNav {
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
#LogoWrapper {
}
#Logo {
}
#LogoTag {
}
.hide_tablet {
display: none;
}
.zeroMargin_tablet {
margin-left: 0;
}
}

/* Desktop Layout: 769px to a max of 1232px.  Inherits styles from: Mobile Layout and Tablet Layout. */

@media only screen and (min-width: 769px) {

.gridContainer {
    width: 88.875%;
    max-width: 1232px;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    clear: none;
    float: none;
    margin-left: auto;
}
#header-wrapper {
}
#rotation {
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 0;
}
#Navigation {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:100;
    top:49px;
    left:0;
    background: #4b8a9f;
    background: rgba(75,134,159, .8);
    color: #ffffff;
    width: 24.0506%;
    margin-left: 0;
}
#Weather {
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 0;
}
#mobileNav {
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 0;
}
#LogoWrapper {
}
#Logo {
}
#LogoTag {
}
.zeroMargin_desktop {
margin-left: 0;
}
.hide_desktop {
display: none;
}
}
```

---

### rotating images CSS

```
.rslides {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  }

.rslides li {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  }

.rslides li:first-child {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  }

.rslides img {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  }
  .caption {
  position: absolute;
  z-index:25;
  display: block;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  margin:0;
  text-align: center;
  background: #4b829f;
  background: rgba(75,134,159, .8);
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size:18px;
  font-stretch:expanded;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `#mobileNav` is appearing behind all of the `#header-wrapper` content because all of the `#header-wrapper` content is using `position: absolute;`. Absolutely positioned elements like `#Weather` and `#Navigation` are removed from the flow of the document as if they were never there. You probably just want to float them into their positions, but if absolute positioning is required, then you'll need to account for them with some space in the parent element.